# Enter a number N, and then the program proceeds to output all powers of two smaller than N. How could I continue?

Tags: python, while-loop

So right now I have this:

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
exponent = 0

while exponent <= number:
    result = 2 ** exponent  
    exponent = exponent + 1
    print(result)
```

For example:
If I input 21 it prints out all 21 numbers, but I need the program to print out the numbers that are less than 21 like so:

```
1
2
4
8
16
```

But not all of 21 numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this loop instead:

```
while 2 ** exponent <= number:
    print(2 ** exponent) 
    exponent = exponent + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop use result to compare to number instead of the exponent, in your version it will run until the exponent is up to N and not the result.

```py
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
exponent = 0
result = 0

while result <= number:
    result = 2 ** exponent  
    exponent = exponent + 1
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something a bit faster.

```
N = int(input())
val = 1
while val < N:
    print(val)
    val += val
```

Comment: Should conditional be val <=N?  Otherwise doesn't work properly for N = 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.

Comment: It depends on the task. Should it be `smaller` or `not greater`.